# Android Application dies after couple of hours

Tags: android

I made an android application with a runnable that checks something ever minute.

But the problem is the application goes [DEAD] after a couple hours without an error messages or anything.
Anybody have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: App standby maybe?

Comment: Any incrementing values maybe? Thinking of a overflow?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: i'm sure that if batteries could speak they would thank you

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a problem, that is actually expected behaviour.

The lifecycle of all apps is managed by the Android OS. It decides whether to terminate an app in order to free resources and keep the system responsive. Apps that are currently is use have priority over paused and background ones. I think in your case the OS just decides to shut down the app because it thinks it's not needed anymore.

There are ways to get around this, but it all depends on what your app actually does. I don't know your implementation details, but may want to look into sticky `Service`s or the `JobScheduler` in order to achieve what you want. Keep in mind that there is no such thing as a perpetually running background task that comes out of the box in Android (not should there be one) and usually implementations have certain limitations.

Comment: I want to application to check if a Wi-Fi SSID name is vissable, and if this is true i want it to send the user a notifaction. What should i use to do this?

Comment: I think you need to use the `JobScheduler`. You can define when your job runs based on a number of criteria. For example, you can run your job only if you are currently on Wi-Fi, etc. Check the docs out.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the Android OS itself closing the app. If the OS requires more memory it will start to kill of other processes that have not been used for a long time (i.e. interacted with). You haven't stated how the check happens but it shouldn't be done directly within the app, but it sounds like it is something that a background service should be doing the work which would likely prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use Runnables for background processes, as they get suspended/killed by the OS as soon as your app goes off-screen.

If you want to let some processes run regularly, you have to stick with `AlarmManager` / `BroadcastReceiver` combination